# Windows Forms designer automatically rescales controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

My Windows Forms designer in Visual Studio resizes and repositions controls whenever I open a design file. It rescales buttons, labels and anything else it can find, moves them by a few pixels and so on, often making them overlap.

This happens in any design file not created on my machine. It is a major annoyance, as whenever I want to commit my intentional changes I have to manually revert dozens of unintended changes to sizes/locations of controls and filter out the intentional changes. I believe it might be the resolution of the monitor that is to blame, but I don't have a way to verify this assumption.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I remove all those statements from the designer file and put into my regular c# code.  I find I can set all the top and left parameters better in my code where I can make the all the boxes exactly align then in the designer where the left and top pixels can be different by tiny amounts.

Comment: Sounds like a dpi issue

Comment: If you let your Forms scale to Font, that's what you get. If your app is DpiAware, set `AutoScaleMode = Dpi`, otherwise try with `AutoScaleMode = None`. Setting the Font explicitly in Controls that inherit the Font from the Parent will also help a lot. If you're working on a Team, you need to set rules for the Team and/or use predefined Templates only.

Comment: Maybe you can try to edit/design your apps in default 96 DPI (100%). And all containers must use the same AutoScaleMode.